# How to externalize configurations with spring.config.additional-location?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I added the following property into my `application.properties` to separate sensitive account infos from the main application.

```
#/src/main/resources/application.properties
spring.config.additional-location=/etc/java/myapp/

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mytable
```

Additional:

```
#/etc/java/myapp/application.properties:
spring.datasource.username=theuser
spring.datasource.password=thepw
```

Result: the properties are not found!

`java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

What am I doing wrong here?

Sidenote: if I add default values, the problem remains. The properties are not overridden!

spring.datasource.username=replaceme
spring.datasource.password=replaceme

Result:
`java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'replaceme'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: Annotate your class where you are doing the DB stuff (dataSource related stuff)... Annotations that can be of help -> @Configuration, Value

Comment: This question is about externalizing `application.properties`. Of course my setup works completely if I move the additional properties to my main ìnternal properties...

Comment: Maybe this SO answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171430/how-can-i-externalize-datasource-configuration-with-spring-boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note : from doc, from spring boot 2.0 `spring.config.location` upgraded to `spring.config.additional-location`

Command line : java -jar name --spring.config.additional-location=/etc/java/myapp/

**spring.config.name and spring.config.location are used very early to determine which files have to be loaded, so they must be defined as an environment property (typically an OS environment variable, a system property, or a command-line argument).**

Comment: This does not help, see my update. it seems the additional config is not taken into account if the path is configured from within the `application.properties` itself?

Comment: which version spring boot? and also did you try command line? `java - jar name --spring.config.additional-location=path`

Comment: most recent. `spring-boot.2.0.5.RELEASE`. I thought it would work exactly as you proposed, but in fact it does not...

Comment: so  this should not be part of `spring.config.additional-location=path` application.properties

Comment: Ok so it has to clearly come from varargs... the question is: what can I do when having multiple applications in a `tomcat` server? Then each application would require it's own additional-location, which is impossible as the property must be provided globally as vararg...

Comment: In that case i will prefer system property or env variable options , if you are running each application with embedded tomcat then command line works prety good, but if you are deploying war in tomcat server then choose system poperty or env variable option

Comment: i d like to know how to use properly spring.config.additional-location when building war file. 
i know that i can use a tomcat variable in  bin/classpath.sh or bin/setenv.sh file like this JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -D spring.config.additional-location=/path/to/my/secret-location".

But I don't wanna let configure that in tomcat config file. As i'm using gradle is there a way to let gradle configure that ?

Comment: i never played with war files, i will try to find it out @soung